# VS 2017 Not Reporting Test Results to TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We have a TFS 2010 build server.  This has been working well with VS 2015 installed and executing the builds, where if any unit tests fail, we get a link to the test results.  We just installed VS 2017 to be used instead of 2015.  Now, we no longer get a link to the test results; instead, the message "No Test Results" is displayed.  Is a setting messed up that is preventing us from seeing these test results or was this integration broken with VS 2017?  Also of note, if I log into the build server and run the tests in VS 2017, they all pass.  The test failure only occurs when they are executed by TFS.

VS 2017 Results
[image: VS 2017 Results]

VS 2015 Results
[image: VS 2015 Results]

Comment: What's the detail error for the failed test? Seems it also failed when you run with VS2015 according to your screenshoot.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT, As you can see with VS 2015, when a test fails you get a report, so that you can follow up on why the tests fail.  With VS 2017, it simply says "No Test Results", with no opportunity to figure out what is going on.  It doesn't bother me that a test fails.  The issue is when I don't know whether a test failed or not.  I found "Cannot connect to Team Foundation Server" in the logs, which has led me to a workaround.  I am currently trying to write up an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being two issues. For the first one I found this in the logs:

Cannot connect to Team Foundation Server http://...
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

To work around it, I had to put this into the mstest.config file:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-15.0.0.0" newVersion="15.3.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

At that point I got in the logs:

Cannot connect to Team Foundation Server http://...
The prompt option is invalid because the process is not interactive.
Parameter name: PromptType

This was solved by passing "/noprompt" to mstest in the build.

Answer (score 0):

There are not any additional setting in VS side to obtain the test result in TFS build summary. First please compare both build logs to see if there are any difference. Check if the test result was published to TFS. In the log there should be something as below:

> Waiting to publish... Publishing results of test run
>   Tfs_Build_User@PROD_AGT4_WCS 2017-09-29 13:59:31_Mixed
>   Platforms_Release to http://:8080/tfs/XXX... .Publish completed
>   successfully.

Since it works well with VS2015 and not with VS2017, suggest you give a try with another build server/VS2017. If it works well on other build server, this issue may related to your VS installation, try to reinstall,use the latest RTM version.

Besides, suggest you upgrade to a version of TFS released in recent memory. TFS 2010 is extremely limited in capabilities compared to TFS 2017. TFS 2010 is sooner unsupported and runs on software configurations that are likewise unsupported. Staying on a platform that outdated is asking for problems.  And XAML build is also depreciated, for the latest TFS2018, we have [removed support for XAML Builds](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2018-relnotes#xaml).